# Same Data, two different results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a SQL call that currently gets data by year and displays in a month by month breakdown as per the code below.

```
SELECT MaterialCode, [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12]
FROM
(SELECT mb.MaterialCode, DATEPART(m, Date) as [dp], Weight 
FROM Issues iss
JOIN MaterialBatches mb ON iss.MaterialBatchId = mb.Id
LEFT JOIN Materials m ON mb.MaterialCode = m.Code
WHERE IssueType = 'MaterialIssue' AND 
DatePart(yyyy,Date) = 2013 
AND Weight > 0
AND (COALESCE(m.IsNonDispenseMaterial,0) = 0 OR CAST((SELECT Value FROM ConfigurationSettings WHERE Name = 'IncludeNonDispenseWeights') as varchar(10)) = 'true')) i
PIVOT (SUM(Weight) FOR i.dp IN 
( [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12] )) as pvt
```

This code now needs to change to make the starting selected month changeable. Using this code below i get a 948 more records \ row back.

```
SELECT Code, [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12]
FROM
(SELECT mb.Code, DATEPART(m, Date) as [dp], Weight 
FROM Issues iss
JOIN Batches mb ON iss.Id = mb.Id
LEFT JOIN Mats m ON mb.Code = m.Code
WHERE IssueType = 'MatIssue' AND   
YEAR(Date) = 2013 AND MONTH(Date) = 01 OR
YEAR(Date) = 2013 AND MONTH(Date) = 02 OR
YEAR(Date) = 2013 AND MONTH(Date) = 03 OR
YEAR(Date) = 2013 AND MONTH(Date) = 04 OR
YEAR(Date) = 2013 AND MONTH(Date) = 05 OR
YEAR(Date) = 2013 AND MONTH(Date) = 06 OR
YEAR(Date) = 2013 AND MONTH(Date) = 07 OR
YEAR(Date) = 2013 AND MONTH(Date) = 08 OR
YEAR(Date) = 2013 AND MONTH(Date) = 09 OR
YEAR(Date) = 2013 AND MONTH(Date) = 10 OR
YEAR(Date) = 2013 AND MONTH(Date) = 11 OR
YEAR(Date) = 2013 AND MONTH(Date) = 12 
AND Weight > 0
AND (COALESCE(m.IsNonDisp,0) = 0 OR CAST((SELECT Value FROM      ConfigurationSettings WHERE Name = 'IncludeNonDisp') as varchar(10)) = 'true')) i
PIVOT(SUM(Weight) FOR i.dp IN 
( [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12] )) as pvt
```

Can you please let me know, where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the parantheses, try this:

```
    SELECT Code, [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12]
    FROM
    (SELECT mb.Code, DATEPART(m, Date) as [dp], Weight 
    FROM Issues iss
    JOIN Batches mb ON iss.Id = mb.Id
    LEFT JOIN Mats m ON mb.Code = m.Code
    WHERE IssueType = 'MatIssue' 
    AND YEAR(Date) = 2013 
    AND Weight > 0
    AND (COALESCE(m.IsNonDisp,0) = 0 OR CAST((SELECT Value FROM ConfigurationSettings WHERE Name = 'IncludeNonDisp') as varchar(10)) = 'true')) i
    PIVOT(SUM(Weight) FOR i.dp IN 
    ( [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12] )) as pvt
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! works perfectly... i think they call that wood through trees!!

Comment: I am a bit sleepy, but what does that big `where` part supposed to do and my it can be shortened to `YEAR(Date) = 2013`?

Comment: @suslov i didn't have a look at that but i think you're right. maybe another case of "wood through trees"  ;-)  edited